# Objective-C categories doesn't allow to add instance variables

Tags: objective-c, properties, categories, ivar

I would like to know why Objective-C design pattern of categories has designed in a way that we cannot able to add instance variables.

And also I came to know that using Objective-C associated objects we can able to do. But I am more interested what is the main reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer edited to talk about instance variables rather than properties.

Adding instance variables to an object changes the object's memory allocation, and requires that the object be recompiled. Categories add new methods to existing objects without requiring a recompile, and therefore can't add instance variables.

As you say, you can add properties where the data is saved & loaded using associative storage.

### EDIT:

If you have a class FooClass with a header like this:

```
//FooClass.h
@interface FooClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bar1;

@end
```

That defines a class with 1 property `bar1` and backed by an instance variable `_bar1`.

An external category of `FooClass` could not add extra instance variables to `FooClass`.

However, you can create a "private category" in the .m file for FooClass that CAN define additional properties (with backing instance variables) to the class. It works because those additional instance variables are known at compile-time, and can be "baked into" the class. Here's an example:

```
//  FooClass.m
@interface FooClass()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString*bar2;
@end

@implementation FooClass

@end
```

Note the extra @interface declaration, with an additional property. Since it's in the same .m file as the implementation, it isn't exposed to other files, but it **is** known at compile-time, so the compiler can add the needed instance variable(s).

Comment: how to demonstrate "Adding stored properties to an object changes the object's memory allocation" . can you pls give me one example. Thanks for your reply

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Please get the terminology correct. Objective-C categories allow you to add properties. They don't allow you to add instance variables.

Comment: rmaddy, good point. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Duncan . Thank you for brief explanation. I understood the concept of categories and extensions.
I still dont understand how upon adding ivar to an object changes its memory location and requires objects to be recompiled.

Comment: @sanjayzed, see the linked duplicate question for a more thorough discussion.